# File is not uploading i am using apache 2.4.33

Tags: php, apache, server

I am trying to use simple php script to upload an image
The code below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Upload your files</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadfile.php" method="POST">
    <p>Upload your file</p>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"></input><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"></input>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
//echo exec('whoami');
//die($_FILES['uploaded_file']);
  if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
  {
    $path = "./img/backend/uploads/enquiry/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
      echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']). 
      " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
      }
    }
   ?>
```

I'm using php 7.1 I've already checked the folder for permissions. But when I try to submit it take me to some page with @custom kind of stuff in url. but if I try to post it without image it works fine.

What is the problem ? I think about apache which is not handle that properly. On my other server its working fine.

Just on this server I use auto ssl, is that the problem ?

See the image it take me like this link looks like its not submitting or rejected by server 
[image]

Comment: After updating to httpd version 2.4.39, we are noticing that file uploads are failing a lot. It seems to happen when the client takes about 10+ seconds to upload the file. We have confirmed that rolling back the apache version solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the path to this

```
$path = __DIR__."/img/backend/uploads/enquiry/";
```

Comment: when submitting the form it redirect to the page not found.

Comment: Yes as you see i have given same page url it needs to submit but when i try to do without image it comes on same page. so i assume its apache or php issue

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a dot in the file path. Try the following:

`$path = "./img/backend/uploads/enquiry/";`

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Upload your files</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" method="POST">
    <p>Upload your file</p>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"></input><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"></input>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file'])){
    $path = "./img/backend/uploads/enquiry/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    echo $path;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']). 
        " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
}
?>
```

Without dot the file path will take script name as well, for example, if your PHP script/file name is "test.php", then without a leading dot in file path will create a path like (www is the folder where your test.php file is saved):

```
/www/test.php/img/backend/uploads/enquiry/
```

And hence it will be an invalid file path, with a leading dot it will skip it (layman terms) and your path will be like:

```
/www/img/backend/uploads/enquiry/
```

And this path is a valid one, hence it will upload.

Comment: HI Thanks for your reply but i have done that got same issue

Comment: https://thinqhomes.com/uploadfile.php check this url and it take to some different url and not even take any thing

Comment: Without having the access to the source code of your "uploadfile.php" I will not be able to help you out. If the source code of your "uploadfile.php" is exactly the same as you posted over here, it will never redirect to other pages. Have you tried to look around your .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes its the same file. This was working fine on my test server but on this server i install openssl than this issue start coming not on this url whole server i cant upload images

Comment: This should not happen, there must be something else. Have you tried restarting the server?